# C# Graphics.DrawString and Graphics.ScaleTransform conflict?

Tags: c#, gdi+

When projecting a unit sphere onto a plane, I want to also draw the original and projected coordinates. Since I've never stopped using WinForms, I am using GDI+ to draw the image:

```
private void btnRender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabMain.SelectedTab = tabRender;
    var tangent = new Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    var xsize = 2048;
    var ysize = 2048;
    var pen = new Pen(Color.Maroon, (float)(1 / xsize));
    var font = new Font("Arial", 10);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    var bmp = new Bitmap(xsize, ysize);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        g.TranslateTransform(xsize / 2, ysize / 2);
        g.ScaleTransform(xsize, ysize);
        foreach (var v in hull.Vertices) {
            foreach (var f in v.VoronoiFaces) {
                var pts = f.Vertices.Select(v1 => (PointF)Projector.Stereographic(v1, tangent)).ToArray();
                g.DrawPolygon(pen, pts);
            }
            var pt = (PointF)Projector.Stereographic(v.Vertex, tangent);
            var str = String.Format("{0}->{1}", v.Vertex, pt);
            g.DrawString(str, font, brush, pt);
        }
    }
    picRender.Width = xsize;
    picRender.Height = ysize;
    picRender.Image = bmp;
}
```

When I render the image, `g.DrawString(str, font, brush, pt);` doesn't draw anything on the screen. It seems `g.ScaleTransform(xsize, ysize);` is the culprit, since when I remove it, all the text gets drawn. I guess it scales the text up and the text gets pushed off the screen. Is there a way to draw the text so that its size is not transformed, but its position is? When I divide the font size by the scale factor, GDI+ throws an exception.

Should I roll with a custom coordinate transformation instead of the builtin one? Or should I switch to a different graphics library? Which one?

Comment: When the text is drawn, is it drawn at the right position? If so, settting and resetting the transform around the inner loop could help.. (Setting a transform is not an expensive thing to do, afaik.)

Comment: It is drawn at the wrong position, of course, since the position is usually between -1,-1 and 1,1.

Comment: That's what I thought. I guess you need to find an adjusted transform for the DrawString. __If__ you are happy with the drawing of the Vertices I see no need to switch to anthing else.. It is a little hard to do without data to play with. Usually making the drawing area really big and the drawing really small helps to find those displaced items..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can draw the text such that only the position is transformed, and not the size. Don't use ScaleTransform. Instead, multiply your text point coordinates by the scaling factors. Or create a Matrix and use that to multiply. The exception you describe is probably from trying to set a font size to 0.